# Negation of conjunctive quantified statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is the negation of:

$ x < y∧(∃z)[x < z < y] $

equal to:

$ x ≥ y \vee (∀z)[(x ≥ z) \vee (z ≥ y)] $

? I am confused on the negation of x < z < y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x<z<y $ is short for $x < z\land z < y$

hence, its negation is $ x \ge z \lor z \ge y$

So yes, you did everything corectly!

Comment: thanks! is the negation of the whole statement correct?

Comment: @user7252850 yeah, the rest was all fine!

Answer (score 1):

We read ($\ref{1}$) as ($\ref{2}$)

$x<y<z\label{1}\tag{1}$

$(x<y) \land (y<z)\label{2}\tag{2}$

so its negation is ($\ref{3}$) as you have identified in your expression.

$(x\geq y) \lor (y\geq z)\label{3}\tag{3}$

The full worked negation is:

$\lnot(x<y \lor (\exists z)[(x<y) \land (y<z)])$

$\lnot(x<y) \land \lnot[(\exists z)[(x<y) \land (y<z)])] $

$(x\geq y) \land (\forall z)[(x\geq y) \lor (y\geq z)])$

So your work is indeed correct.